# Get Rid of Wrong JRE Warning When Importing an HTML/JavaScript Project Into Eclipse

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse, maven

When importing a maven project that uses HTML and JavaScript, but not Java, I get messages about wrong JRE's. But there is no Java used, so I find these messages a 'bit' strange.

I can remove the paths in Eclipse and the warnings go away, but after a 'Maven -> Update project' those warnings are back.

Comment: There are plenty of questions here from people using Eclipse for web projects so they are managing OK.

Comment: I guess the problem is a wrong usage of Maven

Comment: @Pino I posted a striped down version of the pom.xml at the original post. I do not see anything wrong with it, but would love to find out what is wrong with it.

Comment: If you are using Maven, *something* about your project involves Java.

Comment: Alternatively, the Maven support in Eclipse assumes it's only ever used with projects involving Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Eclipse assumes that a maven project involves Java. When I create the following pom.xml and nothing else and import it, I get the same messages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
 xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <name>Foo Client Application</name>
    <description>The Foo client, enabling local users and remote partners to work together.</description>
    <url>https://www.Foo.com/</url>
    <groupId>com.Foo.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>Foo-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

</project>
```

---

The solution is to not to import the project as a maven project.
Instead do the following:
File -> Import -> General -> Projects from Folder or Archive

I still get the messages about the wrong JRE, but now I can delete them and they do not reappear.